# Unable to configure to native resolution on LCD of retina macbook pro

Tags: display, resolution

I have late 2015 issue macbook Pro with `2880x1800` native resolution. How do I *use* that resolution? The max that I can configure using the built-in tools is `1920x1080`.

I am on High Sierra.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's System Preferences don't allow you to change to full native resolution.

You can use the [displaymode](https://github.com/p00ya/displaymode) command line tool to change to the native resolution.

Download the binary from the "releases" section, and extract it if necessary.  Then from Terminal.app, `cd` to the directory the `displaymode` file is in and run:

```
./displaymode t 2880 1800
```